# Is there a way to find version of lua interpreter?

Tags: debian, lua

Unlike python, lua doesn't seem to have a way of giving version details.

With python -

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15+

$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.6
```

There are multiple versions of lua on my system, but couldn't find anything within the packages which would tell me what is a good way.

Edit: You actually have to give version info.

```
$ lua5.3 -v
Lua 5.3.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

Update -

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config lua-interpreter
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for lua-interpreter
```

ideally shouldn't this be done the packager rather than us ?

Anyways here's a paste which tells most of the things.

https://paste.debian.net/1048330/

I did do the following however, dunno whether it's right or wrong -

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /etc/alternatives/lua-interpretor lua /usr/bin/lua5.3 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/lua5.3 to provide /etc/alternatives/lua-interpretor (lua) in auto mode
```

Comment: it seems disingenous to have to know the version of lua before you want to know the version of lua

Answer (score 1):

From [the `lua` docs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/lua.html):

```
-v show version information.
```

Comment: there doesn't seem to be just a lua -v in Debian, at least couldn't find it, need to give some liblua5.x -v to get the actual version.

Answer (score 1):

Use `apt` or `dpkg` ... :

```
dpkg -l lua* | grep ^ii
```

or

```
dpkg-query -l lua* | grep ^ii
```

The `lua -v` will print **the default** `lua` version.

The default `lua` can be edited throught:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config lua-interpreter
```

Before using the above command you should update your `update-alternatives` through the `--install` option to inclued all the installed `lua` versions.

**Update**

As said @shirish ,there are a  bug in `lua5.3` ( [#863036](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=863036) ):

To solve this issue , run the following commands (using the 130 priority because lua5.1 is pinned to 110 and lua5.2 is pinned to 120):

```
update-alternatives  --install /usr/bin/lua lua-interpreter /usr/bin/lua5.3 130 \
--slave /usr/share/man/man1/lua.1.gz lua-manual \
/usr/share/man/man1/lua5.3.1.gz
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/luac lua-compiler /usr/bin/luac5.3 130 \
--slave /usr/share/man/man1/luac.1.gz lua-compiler-manual \
/usr/share/man/man1/luac5.3.1.gz
```

Also the manpage will be available after installing `5.3` on your system.

Check it:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config lua-interpreter
```

Set it as default then :

```
lua -v
```

Comment: I updated my query and whatever I could but dunno if I did the right thing or not.

Comment: just found there is a bug listed for this https://bugs.debian.org/863036